# htaccess /index.php?u=xx&p=yy to /xx/yy/ URL rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to know how to URL change `/index.php?u=xx&p=yy` to `/xx/yy/`.

index.php will be removed and u and p values become with a slash mark.

htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(/.*)?/?$ /$1$2 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

I have used the above code but it only removes index.php. Others are remaining the same.

Comment: You already asked pretty much the same thing, only an hour ago. [URL Rewrite like Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71331364/url-rewrite-like-facebook)

Comment: @CBroe, that answer could be made duplicate of this, since that doesn't have answer IMHO, making this answer dupe of that(not having answer) doesn't make sense to me, cheers.

Comment: "Others are remaining the same" - what does that mean? Which "others" remain? And what have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase, OP has already mentioned tried htaccess code`I have used the above code` in question IMHO, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following htaccess rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Also please make sure that your htaccess rules file and index.php files are in same directory.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect rules as follows:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/p/index\.php\?u=([^&]*)&p=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules as follows:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?u=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I put URL like this www.xx.com/p/index.php?u=aa&p=ff but it is remaining the same. I try to access like this www.xx.com/p/aa/ff/ it give error 404.

Comment: @Indra, Is `p` fixed before `index.php` always?

Comment: Yes but I need every page like www.xx.com/ggg/index.php

Comment: basically, link can be /index.php?xxx=aa&yyy=ff, xxx and yyy can be anything but final url is /aa/ff/. aa and ff are values. It is actually format-changing.

Comment: @Indra, I have edited my rules now, please try hitting `www.xx.com/p/index.php?u=aa&p=ff ` once. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URls.